# Limit Process Memory Usage

Tags: asp.net-core, ubuntu, hangfire, kestrel-http-server

A question related to the .NET process and in this case the **dotnet** command.

Here's the scenario, I'm running various .NET Core web applications on an Ubuntu server using **Kestrel - Apache** as a reverse proxy following the [Microsoft Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

The question is: Is there a way to limit the memory used by each dotnet process or a workaround to do it so? Before any question, the reason why limiting the memory is: that I have a Web Application running [Hangfire Server](https://www.hangfire.io/) which consumes a lot of memory and it's not limited and I would like to better control the memory allocated to any application.

I tried to look into [runtimeconfig.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/) file but I didn't find anything.
If there is no way, maybe some way to limit the memory of a Linux process could do the trick?

Many thanks!